# baud rate parameter in rosserial_python arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying serial communication between the Arduino and ROS using rosserial (http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial). It works perfectly with the default parameter for the baud rate:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0
```

but when I give a different baud rate using this:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=9600
```

I get the following error:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1428602466.003588] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1428602466.016732] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 9600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1428602483.124382] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

I have rosserial-indigo-devel installed and the ROS version is indigo. The above error comes only when you specify a baud rate other than 57600 (default baud rate).
I also looked into serial_node.py and changed the default baud rate to 9600 but then also, it only works with the baud rate of 57600 and gives error if some other baud rate is specified.

Does anyone know what can be the problem?

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206972/baud-rate-parameter-in-rosserial_python-arduino/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set the baud rate in your Arduino code by using `nh.getHardware()->setBaud(BAUD)` before you initialize the node. BAUD would be 9600 in your case.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwiesz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/23432/kwiesz91/) on 2015-08-11**:
Thank you so much!  I have been wondering how to do this!

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2017-12-31**:
Is it also possible to specify the serial port e.g. Serial1, Serial2 for Arduino mega or a software serial port?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So..rosserial_arduino was always setting the baud rate of arduino as 57600. So, for rosserial_python, only the baud rate of 57600 was working.I made rosserial_arduino run at the baud rate of 9600 (or 19200, etc.) by editing `ArduinoHardware.h` in `<sketchbook>/libraries/ros_lib` and then specified the same baud rate for rosserial_python and it is working now.
Just make sure to change the baud rates for both rosserial_arduino and rosserial_python if you want to use a non-default baud rate.

---

Originally posted by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) with karma: 1464 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2